# Вопрос по парсингу html страницы

Tags: python

Всем привет! Решил написать парсер html странички, задумка такая: скрипт первым post-запросом получает нужную страничку, вторым get-запросом- ее содержимое (сниф запросов на сайт показал, что именно так и происходит- сначала post, потом get). Далее с помощью BeautifulSoup ищем нужное слово и print если слово найдено. Потом циклом переключаемся на следующую страницу и так далее. Но на get-запросе выходит ошибка, не могу понять почему:

```
C:\Python\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:181: UserWarning: No parser was expl
icitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("
lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system
, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behav
e differently.
```

сам код парсера:

```
import requests
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import lxml

mainurl = r'нужный урл'
def postzapros ():
    url1 = 'урл'
    headers = {
    хедеры
    }
    telo = {
    тело запроса
    }
    r = requests.post (url1, headers = headers, data = telo)
def getzapros ():
    g = requests.get ("урл2")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(g.text)).find_all('тут пишу то, что нужно найти')
    print (soup[i].text)
for i in range (5):
    try:
        postzapros ()
        time.sleep (2)
        getzapros ()
    except Exception:
        break
```

Comment: Не понимаю зачем тут пост запрос вообще, странный парсер

Comment: сайт своеобразный. заходишь на него post запросом, он присваивает тебе имя. get запросом получаешь информацию, которую сайт присвоил твоему имени

Comment: Можете дать ссылку?

Comment: нет к сожалению

Comment: Это не ошибка - это не критическое предупреждение. Его можно перевести как "`Вы явным образом не указали, какой парсер использовать, поэтому я буду использовать лучший доступный HTML парсер на данной системе (lxml). Обычно - это не проблема, однако разные парсеры могут вести себя по-разному, в том случае, если вы будете запускать этот код на другой системе или другом виртуальном окружении`". Можете явно указывать используемый парсер вторым параметром: `BeautifulSoup(''.join(g.text), 'lxml')`, тогда вам нужно будет добавить `lxml` в список зависимостей

Comment: ок сейчас попробую, а вот эта конструкция правильная? будет ли BS искать по g.text нужное слово? ` soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(g.text)).find_all('тут пишу то, что нужно найти')`